# Haskell : Couldn't match expected type ‘a -> a’ with actual type ‘Failable (a -> a)’

Tags: haskell, functor

I'm trying to experiment with functors and safe division in Haskell, but I got this little error, and I can't really figure out why.

here goes my code :

```
module Main
where

data Failable a = Failure String | Success a

instance (Show a) => Show (Failable a) where
    show (Failure s) = "Failure : " ++ s
    show (Success x) = "Success : " ++ (show x)

instance Functor Failable where
    fmap f (Success x) = Success (f x)
    fmap _ (Failure s) = Failure s

(//) :: (Num a) => Failable a -> Failable a -> Failable a
_ // (Success 0) = Failure "Division by zero"
x // y = fmap (fmap (/) x) y

main = do
    print $ (Success 1) // (Success 2)
```

And the output :

```
main.hs:16:16:
Couldn't match expected type ‘a -> a’
            with actual type ‘Failable (a -> a)’
Relevant bindings include
  y :: Failable a (bound at main.hs:16:6)
  x :: Failable a (bound at main.hs:16:1)
  (//) :: Failable a -> Failable a -> Failable a
    (bound at main.hs:15:1)
Possible cause: ‘fmap’ is applied to too many arguments
In the first argument of ‘fmap’, namely ‘(fmap (/) x)’
In the expression: fmap (fmap (/) x) y
```

Comment: `fmap` expects a function, whereas the expression `fmap (/) x` produces a `Failable (a -> a)` (because `/` is a binary function). Maybe you're looking for `ap` instead of `fmap`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are trying to lift `(/)` to the `Failable` functor.
You could achieve that using pattern matching, but I think you want to do it using the `Functor` functions (`fmap`), alone.

This is however impossible. At best, `fmap (/)` can provide

```
(/)      :: Num a => a          ->           a -> a
fmap (/) :: Num a => Failable a -> Failable (a -> a)
```

and we have no general way to turn that ugly `Failable (a -> a)` into `Failable a -> Failable a`.

This is why we have a more powerful type class: `Applicative`, for doing precisely that

```
(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

So... congratulations. You have just discovered the issue for which such a type class was introduced.

I'd recommend you write a `Applicative` instance. After that, (omitting the zero check)

```
(//) = liftA2 (/)
-- or, (this being the most popular style, nowadays)
x // y = (/) <$> x <*> y
-- or,
x // y = fmap (/) x <*> y
```

Answer (score 2):

I've come up with this definition instead:

```
(//) :: (Eq a, Fractional a) => Failable a -> Failable a -> Failable a
_ // (Success 0) = Failure "Division by zero"
f@(Failure _) // _ = f
_ // f@(Failure _) = f
(Success v) // y = fmap (/v) y
```

What happens with your definition is that you are passing to `fmap` in the second equation of `(//)`, something of type `Failable (a -> a)`, where it expects to have something of type `a -> b`.

What you can do is to make it an instance of `Applicative`, and make your `Functor` to be applicative, as follows:

```
class (Functor f) => Applicative f where  
    pure :: a -> f a  
    (<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

And make an instance of your functor likewise:

```
instance Applicative Failable where
  pure = Success
  (<*>) fun (Success x) = fmap (\f -> f x) fun
```

Therefore, you can define `(//)` as follows:

```
(//) :: (Eq a, Fractional a) => Failable a -> Failable a -> Failable a
_ // (Success 0) = Failure "Division by zero"
x // y = (<*>) (fmap (/) x) y
```

**UPDATE:**

As Asad pointed out in the comments, a more natural and clearer way to write the last line would be:

```
x // y = (/) <$> x <*> y
```

Comment: A more natural way to write that last implementation might be: `(/) <$> x <*> y`.

Comment: You guys are amazing, I just started out on Applicatives, thanks for the response